# How tto switch eclipse to dark theme

Tags: eclipse, darkmode

I've looked through several websites and stack overflow questions and none of them solved my problem. I am running eclipse on windows 10 and when I switched to dark theme, the console and editor changed, but all the labels are still the same. How do I fix this?

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: What does "all the labels stay the same" mean? What is supposed to be the problem in that image? It looks OK to me.

Comment: @greg-449 I mean where it says "eclipse-workspace - Eclipse IDE" at the top, is there any way to change the color of that

Comment: The operating system controls the colour of the window title not Eclipse.